# RESTful naming convention for combined children of all parents

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have a RESTful API designed like this:

- `/api/v1/parents` - returns all parents
- `/api/v1/parents/%d/children` - returns all children for given parent

Now I would like to have an endpoint that returns all children of all parents in a single call. What would be good naming for such endpoint? Is `/api/v1/parents/children` good shot?

Answer (score 1):

> RESTful naming convention

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your resource identifiers.

> Is /api/v1/parents/children good shot?

- `/api/v1/parents/children` is fine.
- `/api/v1/children` is fine.
- `/api/v1?children` is fine.
- `/53C670D3-B589-4039-9F7C-9A247323C895` is fine.

Comment: I know, but there usually are some good practices and conventions. I thought that maybe there is a widely adopted convention for such cases. ;)

Comment: @slakomy While it is pretty common to have something like `http://host:port/some/path/to/resource` and plenty of people in their mindset compare it to actual file-path where `some` is a directory, `path` is a further directory in that `some` directory and so forth and `resource` actually being a file or leaf inside that tree or directory structure, actually there is nothing specifying such a structure in an URI. The URI as a whole is just a pointer to a resource. You'd might introduce plenty of URIs that actually span such a tree, but it is not a must